# Error: error setting up new vSphere SOAP client: Post "https://example.com/sdk": dial tcp: i/o timeout

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-vsphere

when I am running "terraform plan" I am getting this error
Error: error setting up new vSphere SOAP client: Post dial tcp: i/o timeout

on modules/control_plane_resources/main.tf line 2, in provider "vsphere":
2: provider "vsphere" {

Comment: Can you provide complete code example?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely, the url you've provided to your Vsphere Client is incorrect. I had the exact same issue and that was the cause.
for example my provider.tf file looked something like this:

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = var.vsphere_user
  password       = var.vsphere_password
  vsphere_server = var.vsphere_server_uri
  # If you have a self-signed cert
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}
```

and my tfvars file had this value:
vsphere_server_uri = "vra@domain.local"

and it should have been this instead:
vsphere_server_uri = "vsphere@domain.local"